# No Wifi after upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, atheros, 22.04

I will preface this by saying I am not technically savey... I updated last night from 20.04 to 22.04 and now my wifi is not working.  It doesn't show a wifi icon in the top right, or in the settings.  Fn+F2 turns on airplane mode, but that's all.  I have searched everywhere on-line, and have been unsuccessful trying everything I've found.

**iwconfig outputs:**

iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

**sudo lshw -C network outputs:**

sudo lshw -C network

*-network UNCLAIMED

description: Network controller

product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter

vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
version: 01
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: memory:b0500000-b057ffff memory:b0580000-b058ffff

nmcli r shows that everything is enabled.

I have tried updating the BIOS, and that didn't work.

There are no additional drivers in the Software and Updates settings.  Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens in terminal if you `sudo modprobe -v ath9k`

Comment: @Jeremy31 - It didn't produce an output.  I ended up backing up my files and doing a clean install.  The wifi works now with the clean install.  Something must have gotten removed during the original upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04...

Answer (score 0):

I found that drivers didn't correctly update on: Ubuntu, Kubuntu, and Budgie. I also found that a clean install would correctly detect hardware, and for the moment have judged the in-place upgrade "not ready for prime time" and will hold off until there is better feedback. This is actually a long-standing issue with almost all flavors of Ubuntu, for whatever reason LTS-> interim releases have full hardware support, but interim (e.g., 21.10) to Long-Term support is pretty terrible. I remember reading a poster on askUbuntu advising to wait till July, now I understand why!